# a2a Facebook wrong data

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using AddToAny in my application. The goal is to share a article on the page. I've read about integrating the Open Graph Meta Tags, which i have done with jquery on the clint-side.

```
var newTitle = $('meta[property=og\\:title]').attr('content', header);
var newDescr = $('meta[property=og\\:description]').attr('content', str);
var newImage = $('meta[property=og\\:image]').attr('content', imageSource);
var newUrl   = $('meta[property=og\\:url]').attr('content', url);
```

The problem is that this information is executed when the document is ready and Facebook seems to load the page plain without any scripts. Then the information isn't set and the wrong information is inserted.

I am using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to test what information it loads.

AddToAny uses the a2a.init() function, which should do the job, but it's still the same deal. https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/multiple_buttons_customize

My code is the following:

```
 var a2a_config = a2a_config || {};
        a2a_config.locale = 'da';
        a2a_config.linkname = header;
        a2a_config.linkurl = url;
        a2a.init();
```

Edit: This is an single-page application with Angular 1.x, but i use Jquery to set the meta tags.

Comment: You can not set the Open Graph meta data via client-side JavaScript, the Facebook scraper does not care about that. Only the HTML code returned by the server when the URL is requested is taken into account.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe i should have mentioned that it is an single-page application, so i have to dynamicly update the tags on every state change. But this doesn't make the case any easier.

Comment: You have to do it on the server. Facebook only reads the HTML